# Javascript.void problem i want to see the page new adress when i click on a href link

Tags: javascript, onclick, href

it works, but i want to see the link adress so that people can bookmark the link, now they click on and they stil see the main link adress"`http://hemsidan/start_media.php`.

`<a class="links_left" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="load_huvud_meny('information.php', 'texten');">Information</a>`

When you click on this link you get this you see this in http://hemsidan/start_media.php

But what i want to see is the links adress `http://hemsidan/information.php`.

[image: This is the resault when you click on the link]

Comment: You want to redirect the user?

Comment: This looks like a job for [Push State](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the link address in the href attribute, while also adding "return false" at the end of the onclick attribute.

```
<a class="links_left" href="http://hemsidan/information.php" onclick="load_huvud_meny('information.php', 'texten'); return false;">Information</a>
```

Comment: No that did not solve it. You can see it down in the status bar but not

Answer (score 0):

What i want to do is that you can see the new adress here

[image]